# Installing dependencies only - setuptools

Tags: python, pip, setuptools, easy-install

I have a Python script, with several external dependencies, that I wish to distribute to colleagues. However, we will need to modify this script regularly so I don't want to *install* it per-se (i.e. copy to `site-packages`). From what I've seen `setuptools` seems to do this implicitly.

Is there a recommended approach to installing dependencies without installing the application/script itself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably want to make sure that you and your colleagues use the same dependencies during development.

I think I would try to use virtualenv for this. If you and your collegues install it, it will give you a python environment for this project only, and dependencies for this project only.

So the steps would be:

1. Everybody installs virtualenv on their computers so they get an isolated environment to use for development of this project only.
2. One of you determine the current dependencies and installs them in your virtualenv.
3. You export a list of your used dependencies using this command:

   (inside virtual environment) pip freeze > requirements.txt
4. You then share this text file with the others. They use this command to import the exact same packages and versions into their virtual environment:

   (inside virtual environent) pip install -r requirements.txt

Just make sure that everybody enters their virtual environment before issuing these commands, otherwise the text file will contain their normal python environment installed packages.

Comment: But this would still require them to manually install those dependencies, no?

Comment: Yes, but its easy. You would generate a list of the packages you use with the "pip freeze > requirements.txt" command, and then you give them the requirements.txt file. They can then use this command to install the same package and versions on their system: "pip install -r requirements.txt". You can share the requirements.txt online somewhere and just make sure to always keep it up to date.

Comment: That looks like a sound strategy. Might be worth putting that in the answer itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can install the package in development mode.  This way changes to the code are reflected immediately, rather than needing the package to be reinstalled, which seems to be the problem you're working around:

```
python setup.py develop
```

Docs: https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#development-mode