# Can I have setuptools install dependencies only?

Tags: python, docker

I have a project structure like this:

```
myproject
├── Dockerfile
├── setup.py
└── myproject
    └── main.py
```

Dockerfile goes something like this:

```
WORKDIR /root/myproject
COPY setup.py .
COPY myproject myproject/
RUN python setup.py install
```

The problem is that every time I change a file and run `docker build .` I have to wait for setuptools to download the universe.

I wish I could do this:

```
WORKDIR /root/myproject
COPY setup.py .
RUN python setup.py install-deps-only # <- this doesn't exist
COPY myproject myproject/
RUN python setup.py install
```

That way, changing a file and rebuilding would be quick (since dependency install is cached in a lower docker image layer.

I see this question: [Installing dependencies only - setuptools](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25209753/installing-dependencies-only-setuptools) which seeks a way to do the same thing, but received more of a workaround than an answer.

Comment: `pip install -e .` or `python setup.py develop` may be sufficient for what you want

Comment: @alkasm not on its own, it complains that the `myproject` directory doesn't exist (which it doesn't, yet).  But it gave me the idea to create an empty directory there.  This allows `pip install -e .` to run, and then in a later step I can put the rest of the project there and install it.  If you want to make an answer to this effect I'll accept.  Otherwise I'll do so myself.

Comment: What about after you copy the project folder? Editable/develop mode means that you will only be working off the package in its raw form, it won't actually build a distribution. The whole point of editable installs is that you can edit the python files without rebuilding all the time. See: https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#development-mode

Is that entirely sufficient for your purpose?

Comment: If I copy the project folder first, then any change `main.py` causes docker to run `pip install -e .` on the next build (rather than relying on a cached layer) and since each build gets run in its own container, that command gets run in a context where prior downloads are not available, so it has to download everything again.

Comment: Create a base docker image with your pinned dependencies already installed

Comment: I agree with you this is needed.  Very frustrating how the answer is "we don't want to support this because it's a bad idea" yet it is a valid use case, and no acceptable workaround is ever offered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setuptools will happily "install" a package whose package directory is an empty directory. The packages listed in setup.py are still considered dependencies, so they get downloaded even if there's no code around to `import` them.

I can get what I want by making sure that that directory is empty the fist time setup.py gets consulted, and populated the second time--at which point my code is actually considered.

To achieve this in a Dockerfile, just mkdir the project dir in a separate layer from where you copy contents into it:

```
WORKDIR /root/myproject
COPY setup.py .

# trick pip into thinking the code is there
RUN mkdir myproject

# install my "project"
RUN python setup.py install

# actually place the code
COPY myproject myproject/

# install my project
RUN python setup.py install
```

The critical piece was ensuring that the code got copied in a higher layer than where the dependencies were installed.  The second call to `setup.py` happens every time I make a code change, but it's quick because my dependencies were already downloaded.  The first call only happens if I modify `setup.py`, which is what you'd want.

This works nicely out of the container too, because there you can do `python setup.py develop` and setuptools need not be run for every change.

Comment: I didn't know it was contentious.  Is there an argument for why a `--deps-only` type solution is a bad idea?  I'd have thought they'd want to reduce the load on the pypi servers by making it easier to cut out needless downloads.

Answer (score 1):

I structure requirements in my setup.py like this:

```
with open('requirements.txt') as f:
    requirements = f.read().splitlines()
```

That way requirements.txt is a file that can be passed to pip like this:

```
$ pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Not sure if this is something you'd consider a workaround, but it works well for me in a very similar scenario.